# Chkconfig on Linux Mint 12 giving tons of errors

Tags: command-line, linux-mint, upstart, chkconfig

I'm trying to disable some services from starting at boot time on my Linux Mint 12 laptop.
So I installed `chkconfig`, which has worked great for me before on Fedora.
However, on Linux Mint 12, it gives me tons of errors. Here is an example, trying to disable the `rsync` service:

```
$ sudo chkconfig rsync off
insserv: warning: script 'K01acpi-support' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'cryptdisks-udev' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `cryptdisks-udev'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `cryptdisks-udev'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'acpid' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `acpid'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `acpid'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'plymouth-upstart-bridge' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `plymouth-upstart-bridge'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `plymouth-upstart-bridge'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'rsyslog' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `rsyslog'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `rsyslog'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'friendly-recovery' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `friendly-recovery'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `friendly-recovery'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'udevtrigger' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `udevtrigger'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `udevtrigger'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'udev-finish' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `udev-finish'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `udev-finish'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'plymouth-stop' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `plymouth-stop'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `plymouth-stop'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'apport' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `apport'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `apport'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'dbus' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `dbus'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `dbus'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'cryptdisks-enable' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `cryptdisks-enable'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `cryptdisks-enable'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'hwclock' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `hwclock'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `hwclock'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'lightdm' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `lightdm'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `lightdm'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'udevmonitor' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `udevmonitor'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `udevmonitor'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'ufw' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `ufw'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `ufw'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'binfmt-support' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `binfmt-support'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `binfmt-support'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'udev' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `udev'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `udev'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'irqbalance' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `irqbalance'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `irqbalance'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'cron' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `cron'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `cron'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'nmbd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `nmbd'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `nmbd'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'plymouth-splash' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `plymouth-splash'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `plymouth-splash'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'procps' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `procps'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `procps'
insserv: warning: script 'acpi-support' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'network-manager' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `network-manager'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `network-manager'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'smbd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `smbd'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `smbd'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'dmesg' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `dmesg'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `dmesg'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'module-init-tools' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `module-init-tools'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `module-init-tools'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'network-interface' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `network-interface'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `network-interface'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'console-setup' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `console-setup'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `console-setup'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'anacron' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `anacron'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `anacron'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'modemmanager' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `modemmanager'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `modemmanager'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'udev-fallback-graphics' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `udev-fallback-graphics'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `udev-fallback-graphics'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'plymouth' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `plymouth'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `plymouth'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'network-interface-security' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `network-interface-security'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `network-interface-security'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'alsa-store' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `alsa-store'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `alsa-store'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'alsa-restore' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `alsa-restore'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `alsa-restore'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'avahi-daemon' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `avahi-daemon'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `avahi-daemon'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'plymouth-log' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `plymouth-log'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `plymouth-log'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'mysql' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `mysql'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `mysql'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'atd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `atd'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `atd'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'hostname' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `hostname'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `hostname'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'cups' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `cups'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `cups'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'hwclock-save' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `hwclock-save'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `hwclock-save'
insserv: script virtualbox: service vboxdrv already provided!
insserv: script virtualbox: service virtualbox already provided!
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'setvtrgb' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `setvtrgb'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `setvtrgb'
```

It seems to have worked when I run:

```
# chkconfig rsync
  rsync  off
```

Is it bad to continue to use `chkconfig`? Can anyone suggest an alternate service-managing program, or a way to fix the errors when running `chkconfig`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is an ubuntu based distro you can also use `update-rc.d`.

```
update-rc.d rsync remove
```

or install `rcconf` wich is a really nice text-based user interface

Comment: Actually, `rcconf` seems to be more of what I'm looking for. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4):

According to this [Linux Mint Community document](http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/chkconfig), `chkconfig` works but does kick out errors.

You should [review](http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/upstart) the [documentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart) on using `upstart` as I believe Linux Mint is moving to this method for controlling system services.